# How to log in in other site with yii2

Tags: php, api, yii2

We have 2 sites, login and password of both are the same. When I log in to the first site I want to be automatically logged in to the second one with the help of API. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: I have tried it with API, but I couldn't send API to the exact  URL.

Comment: Which API you have tried?

Comment: $data=array("LoginFormKK" => $text_json);
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
"Content-Type" => "application/json",
"X-HTTP-Method-Override"=>"POST",
             "Cache-Control"=>"no-cache"
));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
$httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);  
curl_close($ch);
?>